# Apache Mina Exception

Tags: java, exception, client-server, apache-mina

i have followed this [link](http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=912) for my example program using apache mina.

these are the lib files which i used with the code.

1. mina-core-2.0.7.jar
2. slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
3. slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar

i am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter cannot be cast to java.util.logging.Logger
    at minafiletrans.MinaServerHandler.<init>(MinaServerHandler.java:12)
    at minafiletrans.Minafiletrans.main(Minafiletrans.java:23)
Java Result: 1
```

here is my code:

```
    package minafiletrans;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.mina.core.service.IoHandlerAdapter;
import org.apache.mina.core.session.IdleStatus;
import org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MinaServerHandler extends IoHandlerAdapter

{
    @SuppressWarnings("NonConstantLogger")
    private final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
@Override
public void sessionOpened(IoSession session)
{
// set idle time to 10 seconds
session.getConfig().setIdleTime(IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 10);
session.setAttribute("Values: ");
}
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("LoggerStringConcat")
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message)
{
logger.info("Message received in the server..");
logger.info("Message is: " + message.toString());
}
@Override
public void sessionIdle(IoSession session, IdleStatus status)
{
logger.info("Disconnecting the idle.");
// disconnect an idle client
session.close(true);
}
@Override
public void exceptionCaught(IoSession session, Throwable cause)
{
// close the connection on exceptional situation
session.close(true);
}

}
```

i have added all the required lib files. then why this error occurs for me. any suggestions to solve this error.

Comment: Can you provide the code at
MinaServerHandler.java line 12 ?

Comment: i have added the code, here is my line 12: @SuppressWarnings("NonConstantLogger")

Comment: I tested your code with a mina project of mine and it worked without problems. Which JRE / JDK version are you using?

Comment: i am using version : java 1.7.0_17

Comment: Isn't this import a problem: import java.util.logging.Logger;
Try using: import org.slf4j.Logger;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not : import java.util.logging.Logger;
but
import org.slf4j.Logger;